# SSRS Report access issue from WebApplication

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I developed SSRS report & Deployed it in a Report Server. I am fetching this report from asp.net web application. Application has its own user name & password. But when i try to click a button in my application to access the report, browser is prompting for user name & password (Server Credential).
Not all the user has server credentials, so i am in a possition to avoid this credential pop-up.
How can i achieve it. Please help on it.

Thanks,

Comment: Whenever you access any report on report server remotly, you need to add server credentials in your code only `c#`. Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983458.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by setting anonymous authentication in Report Server IIS.